# Sinatra Backbone Haml JST Templates

Tags: ruby, backbone.js, sinatra, haml, jst

So I downloaded the Coffee Sinatra Boilerplate repo (https://github.com/timwingfield/backbone-sinatra-boilerplate) as a starting point for playing around with both Backbone and Sinatra.

A lot of my past Ruby experience I'd used Haml as the templating/markup language, so I decided to setup Haml for the repo.

I replaced the file `views/templates/title.jst.tpl` with `views/templates/title.jst.haml`, and added the haml.js file to the js vendor folder, specifying it as a dependency in server.rb to deal with the `undefined: Haml is not a function` error.

Now the error I'm trying to deal with is

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` pointing at `return c["templates/title"].apply(this, arguments);` in the outputted jst.js:

```
(function(){
  var c = {};
  if (!window.JST) window.JST = {};
  JST["templates/title"] = function() {
    if (!c["templates/title"]) c["templates/title"] = (Haml.compile("%h2 My Blog\n"));
    return c["templates/title"].apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That javascript is the result of the `Sinatra::JSTPages` module, which transpiles my coffeescript template into html templates for use by Backbone.js, I haven't written that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is an issue with the gem, switching to the (currently pending) Pull Request (`https://github.com/rstacruz/sinatra-backbone/pull/12`) fixes the error I'm getting.